# Check if variable is none, but let pass if just one object/array

Tags: python, opencv

I use cv2 library to detect objects on image. This function `circles = cv2.HoughCircles(..)` can return `None` or an array of circles found on image. The problem I find is to check if a circle is found.

This might be caused because:
***circles*** – Output vector of found circles. Each vector is encoded as a 3-element floating-point vector (x, y, radius)

So how can I check if this function returned 3 circles or just 1 circle (and it has 3 values)?
My check works if no circle is found, then I get an error.

Code:

```py
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(..)
if circles != None:
    if circles.any():
        #DOSOMETHING
```

The error on line `if circles != None:`:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Why is this even an error and not a warning?

**Question:** how to pass with array of circles or a single circle? How can I tell them apart inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can also see on [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), the recommended way to check if an object is `None` is the following:

```
if circles is not None:
    if len(circles) == 3:
        # DOSOMETHING
    else:
        # DOSOMETHING
```

To check that the array `circles` contains exactly 3 elements, you only need to look at its length.

Comment: This works. The function seems to always return an array of arrays, so I simply do len(circles) and always get the number of circles. :)